# Why does my program skip to completion if a float is entered first, but works with integers?

Tags: c

The problem I occurs when I input any float as the first number. Everything else just goes to completion, but the output looks like a stored memory address perhaps?
If I use any integer the program works properly. I would like for the program to convert any numerical input from the user into integers.
While I explicitly ask for an integer input, if the user inputs 2.2 I would like the program to call it 2, and then move onto asking for their second input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // creating two variables
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    //asking user to input a number
    printf("Enter your first integer value: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
    printf("\nThe integer value you entered is %d.\n", firstNumber);

    //asking user to enter another number
    printf("\nEnter your second integer value: ");
    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);
    printf("\nThe second integer value you entered is %d.\n", secondNumber);

    /* system("pause"); */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/scanf

Comment: you are scanning the input into an "int", that means it has memory assigned for an int and only an int. You can't scan a float into it. You should scan into a float and then convert it as you wish.

Comment: " if the user inputs 2.2 I would like the program to call it 2" --> What if `".2"` is entered, what should code do?

Comment: Good question. I hadn't thought about that. I guess for my purposes I can assume that won't be an issue. My task: Write a Program that reads in 2 integers and then outputs their sum, product, remainder and average. I was just expecting my professor to test it out with a non-integer to see if we had thought about it. It's my first assignment in my first programming class. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @ACH If possible, avoid `scanf()` and use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input into a _string_.  In this case, code can then parse the string multiple times   as an `int`, `float` or whatever.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Try `if (scanf(...) != <expected_value>) {fprintf(stderr, "Error: bad input\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first `scanf()` successfully reads the whole number part of the float as an integer and then the second `scanf()` tries to read another integer but fails because it runs into the decimal point.  The thing to realize is that [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for an integer will stop reading when it hits an non-numerical character, and that it will leave that character in the input stream.